# Обработка изображения

Tags: .net, c#

Дан графический файл. Необходимо уменьшить его размер за счёт ухудшения качества изображения.
Как организовать этот процесс максимально быстро?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это реализуется сохранением изображения в формат с потерей качества, например Jpeg. На MSDN есть [статья об этом](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb882583.aspx). Общая суть сводится к коду:

```
void SaveBitmapWithQuality(Bitmap bitmap, int quality, Stream outputStream)
{
    if (quality < 0 || quality > 100)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
           "quality", "quality must be in [0..100].");
    }

    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
        .Where(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid).Single();
    var qualityEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityEncoder, quality);
    bitmap.Save(outputStream, jpgEncoder, encoderParams);
}
```

И делать, например, так:

```
using (Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("image1.png"))
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(
    "image2.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    SaveBitmapWithQuality(image, 50, stream);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Я делал это с помощью Image.GetThumbnailImage. Делает превьюшку с заданными размерами и без потери качества. Пример дать не могу - исходник потерялся, но, думаю, в виду простоты, это и не нужно.

Comment: Мне кажется, что речь шла не о разрешении (размере в пискелях), а о размере в байтах.